# rpmbuild spec file %install section error

Tags: linux, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have a spec file which is similar to:

```
BuildRoot: /tmp/build_%{name}-%{version}-%{release}

%prep
...
...

%install
# Directories
install -m 755 -d %{buildroot}/usr/app/mypackage/config
install -m 755 -d %{buildroot}/usr/app/mypackage/src
....

# Bash script
install -m 755 script/script1.sh %{buildroot}/usr/app/mypackage/config/script1.sh
install -m 755 script/script2.sh %{buildroot}/usr/app/mypackage/config/script2.sh
install -m 755 script/myapp-log %{buildroot}/etc/logrotate.d/myapp-log
```

When I run the rpmbuild I get the error:

```
install: cannot create regular file `/tmp/build_my_app-1.0-2/etc/logrotate.d/myapp-log'
```

I can get around this by manually creating the `/etc/` and then `/etc/logrotate.d` directories in the `/tmp/build_my_app-1.0-2/` directory.

When I re-reun the rpmbuild it will work.

I guess this is because I am not creating this directory in my install section but as its not directly related to my application I don't want to put that in.

My guess is that there is some clever tag I can use to fix this so that the build will work without any manual intervention.

**My Question:**
Could someone please suggest a way for me to achieve this (assuming its possible) or whether I need to write a script around the rpmbuild to set this up first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the step to create the installation directories in your %install section.  Remember that since you can build in "different" roots, you cannot expect certain directories (like ${buildroot}/etc) to be present.

Try adding

```
 mkdir -p ${buildroot}/etc/logrotate.d
```

just before the install command that copies the file into `${buildroot}/etc/logrotate.d`.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. Would `install -d ${buildroot}/etc/logrotate.d` be a better option than `mkdir`? I'm just wondering as most linux systems seem to already have logrotate setup and I don't want any errors at build or install time

Comment: @ghostJago, The install commands are not to install to the operating system at deployment time, they are to install into the ${buildroot} so the %files section can then start to verify the build properly placed all the expected files in their expected locations.  You can use `install -d` or `mkdir -p`, it doesn't really matter, neither of those commands will be ran when you do `rpm --install package.rpm`